# How to gather table data from a dynamic webpage using python

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, httpwebrequest

I found a script here while trying to learn some automation. I would like to ask any idea how I can gather table data in this page to create the range of other data.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver.exe')
url = "https://poocoin.app/tokens/0x84B7BB9614Cf28226d1b0a07499472bc107e3000"
driver.get(url)
time.sleep(8)
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'lxml')
ts = soup.find('div', class_='px-3')
x = list(ts.stripped_strings)[:5]
print(f'{x[0]}\n{x[1]}\n\n{x[2]}{x[3]}\n{x[4]}')
driver.quit()
```

This snippet produces

```
Total Supply:
1,000,000,000,000

Market Cap:(Includes locked, excludes burned)
$13,628,706
```

I wanted to add some data gatherings like this

```
Total Supply:
1,000,000,000,000
Market Cap:(Includes locked, excludes burned)
$13,628,706

Token tx: gather all data in table
22,393,317 EVCoin       $362.31 0.6631 BNB      $0.00001618 Pc v2   7:12:05 PM  0xc91f Track
1,349,169 EVCoin        $21.94 0.0402 BNB       $0.00001626 Pc v2   7:09:29 PM  0x1a66 Track
23,352,496 EVCoin       $378.22 0.6923 BNB      $0.00001620 Pc v2   7:09:14 PM  0xf023 Track

Buyers: gather all data in table
0x5fd786234dd1ee51935acf7aaa8520c64528466b  $63,289.65  Track
0x31e0021c8ee0daf586748d99b9eed2d225025f1b  $41,561.69  Track
0xf6e14cb70ee7362d1bc38f3e5b034c3e19244b4d  $40,500.91  Track

Sellers: gather all data in table
0x5fd786234dd1ee51935acf7aaa8520c64528466b  $57,658.25  Track
0x31e0021c8ee0daf586748d99b9eed2d225025f1b  $41,254.94  Track
0x34f07245271171d151ce91c00e6feb4615f55cb7  $32,866.42  Track
```